Как сделать загрузку Windows по умолчанию, установленную вместе с MacOS?
На MacBook установлены две ОС - Windows, MacOs. По умолчанию, загружается родная ОС, для загрузки 2й - зажимаю alt при включении. Чтобы сделать Windows загружаемой по умолчанию, попытался в MacOs в Загрузочные тома выставить раздел с win, но в списке только 2 загрузочный тома - MacOs, сетевой(и то он с вопросом). В списке загрузочных томов нет тома с виндой, но через перезагрузку с зажатым alt попасть в нее можно. Через MacOS также можно зайти в раздел диска с виндой.
Версия MacOs 10.5.1
Win 7
Как можно решить проблему?
